# All Url is showing all posts

Tags: wordpress

I recently updated my wordpress version to 3.9.1 Since then, my website shows all recent posts always for any url request. This can be checked in hechtundbarsch.de

Any URL -> category or specific post or specific page will always show all posts. I don't understand why..

Can someone pls help?

Regards
Uma

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that .htaccess file lost write permission and it entered into unending loop with permalink structure configuration

I assigned write permission to .htaccess file & everything started working perfectly now.